# How to get comment depth in a view template?

Tags: theming, comments

How can I get the depth of a comment in a view template? I can see the depth when I load the comment in the comment template, but it doesn't seem to be available elsewhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is special field in views to get depth of comment. It's "Comment: Depth". Just add it in your view and use in your template.

Comment: Wow, I was overthinking that. Thanks. Also, how can you filter on it? I don't see that option.

Comment: I too. Seems you should create custom handler to make filter by depth.